# Insert once, but two records created in MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 3; $i++)
{
    if(!empty($_POST['fl' . $i]))
    {
        $dml = "insert into flAptitude(accountId,language,qualification,certificate) value($accountId,'" . $_POST['fl' . $i] . "','" . $_POST['qualification' . $i] . "','" . $_POST['certificate' . $i] . "')";
        mysql_query($dml,$con);
        file_put_contents("fl$i.txt",$dml);
    }
}
```

And there are only fl1.txt created,whose content is:

```
insert into flAptitude(accountId,language,qualification,certificate) value(1,'Germany','Excellent',NULL)
```

So,under what condition will MySQL generate 2 record for 1 "insert" statement?

**EDIT**
Here is the table definition:

```
mysql> show create table flAptitude\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: flAptitude
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `flaptitude` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `accountId` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `language` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `qualification` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `certificate` varchar(20) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does it have anything to do with AUTO_INCREMENT=3?What does it mean?

Comment: You should also look out for SQL injection issues.

Comment: Please see this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks) on avoiding SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I'm testing it on localhost,so there is no attack.

Comment: @Shore: John doesn't mean that a SQL injection is the cause of your problem, just that this db method is dangerous. You should read up on mysql_real_escape_string() and related built-in functions to be safe when your code goes out into the wild world.

Comment: What is the content of both of those rows?  Are they the same?  Is there any code outside of this function?  As in, do you execute `mysql_query()` again?

Comment: The same,and I didn't execute mysql_query() again.

Comment: Does MySQL accept 'VALUE' as equivalent to the SQL standard 'VALUES' in the INSERT statement?  Does mysql_query() return a status?  Did you check it?  Did you record it?

Answer (score 3):

Occam's Razor tells me that you've probably looped through this thing twice with an outer loop. This could also occur if you had a malformed trigger on the table that was duplicating results. Aside from that, we'd need to see what the `select * from flAptitude` was before and after this code ran to get a better sense as to what it was doing.

`AUTO_INCREMENT=3` just means that the autoincrement column starts at 3 instead of the default 1.

Also, you're using InnoDB, which is an [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) database engine. This means that you're calling your insert twice in your code, you just need to find out where.

Comment: The table was empty before,and with two records after this statement.And there is no outer loop.

Comment: Then you're calling it twice somehow. I recommend putting an `echo` in that loop to figure out when it's being called.

Answer (score 2):

This is a php issue, not a problem with MySQL. The issue is `file_put_contents()` overwrites the content of the file.  Therefore, when your loop happens (loops twice) your log only has the *last* record inserted.

Try this:

```
$file = "fl{$i}.txt";
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $dml . "\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

More on `file_put_contents()` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: That doesn't explain why he had two of the same `$i` being inserted.

Comment: Wait he doesn't say 2 of the same $i, just 2 records are inserted. Occam's on my side!

Comment: There's a reference to $_POST. Could the user be double clicking the submit button?

Comment: Used your method,only to find that it got run for once only.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last part of your question, no it has nothing to do with AUTO_INCREMENT, which is an [attribute to auto-id new rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-auto-increment.html), in this case starting at 3

Answer (score 1):

You wrote your questions in 2009 but maybe my answer will be useful for others...

I had the same issue. In my case it was the FirePHP. Add-on to chrome/firefox. It (I don't know why) doubled my scripts. When I lunch browser without extensions everything was OK.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue to be solved by putting an `exit();` after my header statement;

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO airline SET
            company         = '$company',
            name            = '$name',
            address1        = '$address1',
            address2        = '$address2',
            city            = '$city',
            st              = '$st',
            zip             = '$zip',
            ph1             = '$ph1',
            ph2             = '$ph2',
            fax             = '$fax',
            email           = '$email',
            web             = '$web',
            date            = '$date'";

  if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    mysql_close();
    die("<p><b>Record Not Added </b><br />" . mysql_error() . "</p>");
  }
  else {
    mysql_close();
    $goto = "Location: $php_self";
    header($goto);
    exit();
  }
```

When I omitted the `exit();`, the code would add 2 records of exact same data, but incrementing IDs.  Adding the exit made the script only write once.

Comment: such a funny bugger you are, that header statement causes an infinite loop and i nearly nuked my database before i realised...